# Why $\mathbb E[|M_t|]\leq C$ for all $t$ implies that $(M_t)$ is uniformly bounded?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In a proof, we proved that there is $C>0$ s.t. $$\mathbb E[|M_t|]\leq C$$ for all $t\geq 0$. And from this, they conclude that $(M_t)$ is uniformly bounded, but I'm not really sure to understand why it's true.

I don't think that it's important, but for information, $(M_t)$ is a positive martingale.

Here the proof where it appears :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that they do not conclude uniform integrability instead of uniform boundedness?

Comment: @K.Power: Yes exactly, but they justify the uniform integrability by the uniform boundness.

Comment: As Kabo Murphy states below they do not conclude uniform boundedness at all, just that the $p$-th moment is uniformly bounded, from which they deduce uniform integrability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely  a false statement. For a positive martingale $EX_t$ is independent of $t$ so $E M_t \leq C$ says nothing at all. Certainly there exist positive martingales which are not uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thank you. I add the proof were it appear. Maybe there is a subtlety that I don't understand.

Comment: @John You have changed the hypothesis and the conclusion. What they are saying is that if $E|M_t|^{p}$ is bounded for some $p >1$ the $(M_t)$ is uniformly integrable. This assertion does not even require martingale property. 'Uniformly integrable' is very different from 'uniformly bounded'.